# RowTemplate RenderFragment not displaying correctly in Blazor table (Mudblazor) when passed into the Base Component

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, mudblazor

I have a BaseMaintenance component that defines the MudTable that gets rendered when it is inherited by other components. In the parent component, I define 3 RenderFragments:

```
private RenderFragment TableHeaders =@<MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<AgreementTypeDTO, object>(x => (object)(x.AgreementDescription != null ? x.AgreementDescription : string.Empty))">Description</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>;

    private RenderFragment<AgreementTypeDTO> TableRowTemplate = item =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"TableRowTemplate invoked with AgreementTypeDTO: {item}");

        return @<MudTd DataLabel="Description">@item.AgreementDescription</MudTd>;
             
    };

    private RenderFragment<AgreementTypeDTO> TableRowEditTemplate => item => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(MudTd));
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "DataLabel", "Description");
        builder.OpenComponent(2, typeof(MudTextField<string>));
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "Value", item.AgreementDescription);
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, (string value) => { item.AgreementDescription = value; }));
        builder.AddAttribute(5, "Required", true);
        builder.CloseComponent();
        //builder.CloseComponent();
    };
```

They are passed into the BaseMaintenance component that is inherited:

```
<MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Large">
    <br />
    <AddNew Size="Size.Medium" TItem="AgreementTypeDTO" Update="StateHasChanged" Data="@Items" />
    <Delete Size="Size.Medium" TItem="AgreementTypeDTO" Update="StateHasChanged" DeleteAction="@agreementTypeService.Remove" OriginalList="@Items" SelectedItems="@selectedItems.ToList()"></Delete>
    <div style="height: 10px"></div>
    <BaseMaintenance TItem="AgreementTypeDTO"
                     Items=@Items
                     TableTitle="Agreement Types"
                     TableHeaders=@TableHeaders
                     TableRowTemplate=@TableRowTemplate
                     TableRowEditTemplate=@TableRowEditTemplate
                     Service="@agreementTypeService" />

    <br />
    <br />
    <EditEventLog @ref="eventLog"></EditEventLog>
</MudContainer>
```

And in the BaseMaintenance Component, the passed in RenderFragments are placed into their respective Table components:

```
<MudTable MultiSelection="true" @bind-SelectedItems="selectedItems" Loading="@_loading" Items="@Items" Hover="true" CanCancelEdit="true" Filter="new Func<TItem,bool>(FilterFunc)"
              SortLabel="Sort By" CommitEditTooltip="Commit Edit"
              RowEditPreview="BackupItem" RowEditCancel="ResetItemToOriginalValues"
              RowEditCommit="ItemHasBeenCommitted" IsEditRowSwitchingBlocked="true" ApplyButtonPosition="TableApplyButtonPosition.Start" EditButtonPosition="TableEditButtonPosition.Start" EditTrigger="@editTrigger">
        <ToolBarContent>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">@TableTitle</MudText>
            <MudSpacer />
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
        </ToolBarContent>
        <ColGroup>
            <col style="width:50px;" />
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
            <col />
        </ColGroup>
        <HeaderContent>
            @TableHeaders
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate>
            @*<MudTd DataLabel="Description">@GetDescription(context)</MudTd>*@

            @TableRowTemplate
        </RowTemplate>
        <RowEditingTemplate>
            @* @TableRowEditTemplate *@
        </RowEditingTemplate>
        <PagerContent>
            <MudTablePager />
        </PagerContent>
        <EditButtonContent Context="button">
            <MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Outlined.Edit" Class="pa-0" OnClick="@button.ButtonAction" Disabled="@button.ButtonDisabled" />
        </EditButtonContent>
        <FooterContent>
            <MudTd colspan="6">Select All</MudTd>
        </FooterContent>
    </MudTable>


private string GetDescription(object obj)
    {
        var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty("AgreementDescription");
        return property != null ? property.GetValue(obj)?.ToString() : "Property not found";
    }
```

With this setup, the table renders without console or runtime errors, however the description field in the table is populated with:
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment`1[PIMS.Service.AgreementTypeDTO]"

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYiPN.png)

Notice the commented out line in the RowTemplate attribute: "@*@GetDescription(context)*@" When I comment out the @TableRowTemplate and invoke this line instead, the function uses the Items that were passed into the BaseComponent and sets them as the context. This works perfectly fine, the table renders all the proper information. However, I cannot do it this way because it defeats the purpose of the abstraction since I don't want to have that GetDescription function in my BaseMaintenance Component, further, all the tables will have different amounts of columns and will requre a RenderFragment anyway to design the RowTemplate.

I cant seem to figure out why the renderfragment isnt passing the actual Blazor markup into the component.

I should note, the TableHeaders RenderFragment works as expected.

I have tried everything and cant seem to figure out this awkward issue with passing the rowtemplate  markup between parent and child component.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to apply the context of those `RenderFragment`'s

```
<RowTemplate>

    @TableRowTemplate(context) // like this

    <TableRowTemplate> // or like this
        @context
    </TableRowTemplate>
</RowTemplate>
```

Here's a simplified version of your question in a snippet.

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEmnYMbUrVKeerkJ)

If you have naming conflicts because of multiple `context`'s then you can use the `Context` attribute to rename the context.

```
<TableRowTemplate Context="rowContext">
    @rowContext
</TableRowTemplate>
```